# Runtime error when adding more than 1 pivot table to existing worksheet

Tags: vba, pivot-table, excel-2007

I have a macro that creates a new worksheet and pivot table (which works just fine). As soon as I try to add a second pivot table to this worksheet, I get this error message.

> Error message: Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

When I create the second pivot in a new worksheet, it works just fine, so I think the issue is  when I select add to existing worksheet.

Here is the code for the second pivot (created using a macro, sorry I'm new to this so it may be a bit messy), error is on line 3. Not sure why it references the pivot table "Calls by Region/Analyst", which is the already existing pivot:

```
Sheets("Sorted Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -7).Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Status]]").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Tables").pivotTables("Calls by Region/Analyst" _
    ).PivotCache.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot Tables!R3C6", _
    TableName:="PivotTable6", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
Sheets("Pivot Tables").Select
Cells(3, 6).Select
ActiveSheet.pivotTables("PivotTable6").Name = "Analyst"
ActiveSheet.pivotTables("Analyst").AddDataField ActiveSheet.pivotTables( _
    "Analyst").PivotFields("Assigned User Name"), "Count of Assigned User Name", _
    xlCount
ActiveSheet.pivotTables("Analyst").PivotFields("Count of Assigned User Name"). _
    Caption = "Number of Calls"
With ActiveSheet.pivotTables("Analyst").PivotFields("Assigned User Name")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.pivotTables("Analyst").CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Analyst"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Here's the code for the second pivot that works when opening it in a *new* worksheet, however I need it in an existing worksheet (at F3):

```
Sheets("Sorted Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -7).Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Status]]").Select
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Tables").pivotTables("Calls by Region/Analyst" _
    ).PivotCache.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet3!R3C1", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable5", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.pivotTables("PivotTable5").Name = "Analyst"
ActiveSheet.pivotTables("Analyst").AddDataField ActiveSheet.pivotTables( _
    "Analyst").PivotFields("Assigned User Name"), "Count of Assigned User Name", _
    xlCount
ActiveSheet.pivotTables("Analyst").PivotFields("Count of Assigned User Name"). _
    Caption = "Number of Calls"
With ActiveSheet.pivotTables("Analyst").PivotFields("Assigned User Name")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.pivotTables("Analyst").CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Analyst"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: Always helps to note exactly which line causes the error

Comment: Oops, sorry! It is the 3rd line in the first code block:

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Tables").pivotTables("Calls by Region/Analyst" _
        ).PivotCache.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot Tables!R3C6", _
        TableName:="PivotTable6", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12

Comment: Maybe there's already a "PivotTable6" on that sheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams there is only 1 other pivot table! I think it just appears as PivotTable6 because I tried recording (and then deleting) the macro a couple times

Comment: @QHarr done! sorry, newbie on here